# sed to multiple replace based on the condition in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Experts i have a text file where i have some mathematic data and there i've hyphen `-` which i need to replace into `0` and `MB` at the end of numbers which also need be removed so, i can get only numbers.

Below is sample data in a file called `file1`:

**Data:**

$ cat file1

```
 3708MB 5073MB 5153MB  0MB
 -    63097MB 9939MB  53376MB
 -    817MB   681MB   271MB
 -    2655MB   692MB   2112MB
```

**What i have tried:**

```
$ /bin/sed   's/\r//g; s/-/0/g; s/MB//g' tt4
 3708 5073 5153  0
 0    63097 9939  53376
 0    817   681   271
 0    2655   692   2112
```

Or just to get columnize it better way via `column` command ...

```
$ /bin/sed   's/\r//g; s/-/0/g; s/MB//g' tt4| column -t
3708  5073   5153  0
0     63097  9939  53376
0     817    681   271
0     2655   692   2112
```

Is there a better to make sure strictly that only replace hyphen `-` which do not have anything in prefix and suffix and same for removing `MB` only if its and the end of the numbers.

Comment: can the hyphen really appear with a prefix and/or suffix in your data? can you give an example?

Comment: With the example you posted your existing sed command produces exactly the output you say you want. That should  tell you it's not a good example as it doesn't provide a way to test the functionality you want. Please [edit] your question to provide an example that we can use to test if a proposed solution actually works or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to think how uniquely you can capture the pattern(s) so to isolate it from any other appearance of the pattern(s).

Here, `-` seems to be surrounded by blank spaces. So you can use that to make it unique from, say, any other text with `-` ( e.g. text-text ).

```
sed 's/ - / 0 /g'
```

for the pattern MB, you can ensure that you are looking for the pattern which is follows  some numbers.

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+)MB/\1/g'
```

so together you can write:

```
sed -r 's/ - / 0 /g;s/([0-9]+)MB/\1/g'
```

Comment: Just Khaithang, thanks for the answer +1 for the same,  this looks promising solution.

Comment: `-r` enables EREs in old versions of GNU sed only. `-E` does the same in modern versions of both GNU sed and in BSD sed so it's more portable across sed variants.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU or BSD sed for `-E`, this may do what you want:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^| )-( |$)/\10\2/g; s/([0-9])MB( |$)/\1\2/g' file
 3708 5073 5153  0
 0    63097 9939  53376
 0    817   681   271
 0    2655   692   2112
```

Comment: ED Morton, Thanks for the answer +1, can you please explain the  `(^| )-( |$)` and `( |$)`.

Comment: `(^| )` means "start of string or blank" and `( |$)` means "blank or end of string" (and in sed by default the "string" in question is a line of input) so it's testing for a `-` on it's own.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the other answers but perhaps more portable:

```
sed '
    s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/  /g
    s/^/ /
    s/$/ /
    s/ - / 0 /g
    s/ \([0-9]\{1,\}\)MB / \1 /g
' tt4 | column -t
```

I've added whitespace guards around MB numbers too. They require at least two space characters (one at each end), so I've replaced the `\r` test with a more general one to ensure the condition.

Adding space at beginning and end of line means `\|` is not required, use of which broke the code on FreeBSD.

---

Or there's `awk` (which is probably easier to read):

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i=="-") $i=0
        if ($i~/^[0-9]+MB$/) sub("MB","",$i)
    }
    print
}' tt4 | column -t
```

Comment: jhnc, thanks for the answer +1 for the same, this looks good one specially `awk` version.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way for each ask.

```
sed   's/\r//g; s/\b-\b/0/g; s/\([0-9]*\)MB/\1/g' bla.txt | column -t
```

1. Using `\b` filters only the whole word, in your case it is `-`, see an example below.

```
    $ echo "bla blablabla" | sed "s/bla/replace/g"
    replace replacereplacereplace
    $ echo "bla blablabla" | sed "s/\bbla\b/replace/g"
    replace blablabla
```

2. Using `\(` and `\)` around `[0-9]*` properly matches `MB` after numbers as you asked for.

So,

```
$ cat bla.txt
 3708MB 5073MB 5153MB  0MB
 -    63097MB 9939MB  53376MB
 -    817MB   681MB   271MB
 -    2655MB   692MB   2112MB
$ sed   's/\r//g; s/\b-\b/0/g; s/\([0-9]*\)MB/\1/g' bla.txt | column -t
3708  5073   5153  0
-     63097  9939  53376
-     817    681   271
-     2655   692   2112
$
```

Comment: Sparrow, thanks for the answer and +1 for the same, however the boundary match `s/\b-\b/0/g`  doesn't work here.

Comment: `\b` is a regular expression extension. Not all `sed`s support it.

Comment: I am using `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`, which should support i believe .

Comment: I think `\b-\b` fails. eg: `a-b` will become `a0b`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/([0-9]+)MB/\1/;s/(\n )-/\10/;ta' input_file
 3708 5073 5153  0
 0    63097 9939  53376
 0    817   681   271
 0    2655   692   2112
```

Comment: this fails for hyphen not followed by space, or not at start of a line: `only replace hyphen which do not have anything in prefix and suffix`